# Is there any way to enable range/column selection with checkboxes without selecting the entire row of an AG Grid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

If we take the example [from the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-selection/#example-selectable-rows-with-header-checkbox), you can see you can put checkboxes in an arbitrary column header or on the rows. But what I actually wanted to achieve was to select the cell or the entire column but not the rows.

If you try to add another checkbox to another column what will happen is that selecting one checkbox select it in all cells with checkboxes on the same row, and I am trying to avoid that.

Anyone had a similar use case? Is there an out of the box way of doing that? If not, is there some minimal example of how to achieve that without using custom renderers?

Answer (score 0):

To select all cells in a specific column or select only some cells in specific column, it is easier to create a custom component and then use the methods provided by ag-grid rather than using the checkbox option that provided by ag-grid.

First of all, to create a custom checkbox header component, we should pass `components` to `GridOption` and apply the renderer of `agColumnHeader` as custom checkbox header component.

Then add the `addCellRange` function at the event trigger on checkbox of the custom checkbox header component.

**Used**

`Grid option`

- [enableRangeSelection](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-options/#reference-selection-enableRangeSelection)
- [components](https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-header/)

`Interface`

- [IHeaderParams](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-header/#header-component-interface-2)

`Grid api`

- [forEachNode](https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-rowNodes-forEachNode)
- [addCellRange](https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-selection-addCellRange)

**Select entire column**

`CustomHeader.tsx`

```js
import { IHeaderParams } from 'ag-grid-community';

  const CustomHeader =  (props: IHeaderParams) => {
    const columnName = props.column.getColId()
    const onSelectCurrentColumn = useCallback(() => {
      props.api.addCellRange({
      rowStartIndex: 0,
      rowEndIndex: null,
      columns: [columnName]
    })
  },[])

  return (
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" onClick={onSelectCurrentColumn}/>
      {props.displayName}
    </label>
  )
};
```

`Index.tsx`

```js
  const components = useMemo<{
    [p: string]: any;
  }>(() => {
    return {
      agColumnHeader: CustomHeader,
    };
  }, []);

  return (
      <div style={gridStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine">
        <AgGridReact
          rowData={rowData}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
          components={components}
          enableRangeSelection={true} // enableRangeSelection must be true
        ></AgGridReact>
      </div>
  );
```

**Select cell by value in column**

`CustomHeader.tsx`

```js
import { IHeaderParams } from 'ag-grid-community';

  const CustomHeader =  (props: IHeaderParams) => {
    const columnName = props.column.getColId()
    let rowIndexList = []

    const onSelectCurrentColumn = () => {
      props.api.forEachNode(node => node.data.athlete === "Michael Phelps" && rowIndexList.push(node.rowIndex))

      const selectSingleCellRange = (index) => {
        props.api.addCellRange({
          rowStartIndex: index,
          rowEndIndex: index,
          columns: [columnName]
        })
      }

      rowIndexList.forEach((rowIndex) => selectSingleCellRange(rowIndex))
    }

  return (
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" onClick={onSelectCurrentColumn}/>
      {props.displayName}
    </label>
  )
};
```

`Index.tsx`

Same as above

**ScreenShot**
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: I wanted to avoid custom renderers. That solution also only adds the checkbox on the header. I would need checkboxes on the header and on the cells. Also selecting cells with range is not the same thing as checking them. You can see they are different actions, or at least this is how I got.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for no-code solution. Assuming you have range selection enabled, click/focus on the first top cell and then `Shift+Cmd+▼`. This combination will select the whole column from top to bottom.

Comment: Yes, but range selection is a enterprise feature if I am not mistaken. But I already have that in mind if implementing checkboxes won't work for me.